# WPF ListView - is it better in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: wpf, listview

I've tried implementing a readonly grid of items using the WPF ListView.

It appears to me that this is a poorly designed and implemented control. (Unlike most of WPF which I like).

Specific issues I've come across:

- Cannot make the last column expand to
  fill the width of the control,
  without writing extra non-XAML code.
  (See  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911243/wpf-extend-last-column-of-listviews-gridview) )
- Have to override some arbitrarily hard-coded values to get a cell template to actually fill the area of a cell. (See  [this blog entry](http://www.interact-sw.co.uk/iangblog/2007/05/30/wpf-listview-column-margins))

To me, these are pretty obvious flaws, implying that this control was rushed through into Visual Studio 2008.

Does anyone know if these have been fixed in Visual Studio 2010?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked out the WPF Toolkit?

It has a `DataGrid` control that does a lot more out of the box than `ListView/GridView`.

http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117

Regarding your particular concerns, though, I'm not sure there's an automatic way to make the last column fill the remaining width of the container (the default is for a "blank" column to fill up the remaining space) [correction: see Edit below]. I do know you there is a `Visiblity` property for the columns, though, which is a huge improvement IMO.

I do have some examples of `DataGrid` that have specially colored cells, and the color goes right up to the edges of the cell, so I think your second concern should be doable.

Just as an example, here's my cell colorizer style:

```
<Style
    x:Key="Main_DataGridCellStyle"
    TargetType="mwc:DataGridCell">
    <Setter
        Property="BorderThickness"
        Value="0" />
    <Setter
        Property="Background"
        Value="{Binding XPath=@Background}" />
    <Setter
        Property="Foreground"
        Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

Also, the `DataGrid` sorts automatically, although I did have to do some pretty heavy template editing to get the arrows to appear correctly :( *Hopefully* this will be fixed by the time VS10 comes out--I'm pretty sure the community is aware of it.

**Edit**

I stand corrected (in a good way). I just tried `Width="*"` with the last column in a test `DataGrid` and it worked like a charm.

Also, this link confirms that `DataGrid` will be part of WPF 4.0, which is part of VS 2010:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/10/26/wpf-4-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Comment: I not believe that the WPFToolkit datagrid offers column star sizing or last column stretch out of the box either. And for a read-only list of data you don't really need a proper datagrid, a templated listview is leaner and does the same thing.

Comment: @Egor, thanks, I did some updating on my answer while you were commenting :)

Comment: Oops, I stand corrected, good to know. Yes, now that I look at it, the column width property is of type DataGridLength, not double.

Answer (score 1):

VS 2010 is not the framework, and as far as I know .net 3.5 sp1 is the latest edition of WPF. I'm not sure if your problems have other solutions, though most likely yes, but certainly the behavior will be the same in VS 2010.

Have you looked into providing your own templates for ListView's rows and column manager?

Edit: If you were asking about upcoming .net 4, the GridViewColumn Width property is still a Double, so it doesn't support star sizing. So most likely the behavior is still the same.

XCeed's datagrid supports star sizing, though in my experience it's also kind of funky, and they have a special stretch mode you can turn on, but honestly, the attached behavior method described in the article you linked is fairly clean and well done. You can toss it in your project pretty much wholesale and just use it.

http://www.ontheblog.net/CMS/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/37/Default.aspx

It's not overriding any "arbitrarily hard-coded values", it's adding a new attached behavior, in this case stretching all columns equally when an attached property "Stretch" is set to true. You'll have to tweak it slightly for your case in order to only stretch the last column.

The attached behavior method is a nice way to go about it, completely reusable, self contained, and keeps your xaml clean without any mess in the code behind.