# Resizing GridView columns after making it visible

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, column-width

**The setup:**

ListView with GridView that is initially hidden when the window is loaded, and then made visible upon a certain user action.

**The aim:**

Be able to set relative width of GridView's columns.

**The problem:**

What I need can be achieved either by using a converter on the width (something similar to the answer [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/3ee5696c-4f26-4e30-8891-0e2f95d69623/)), or by adding a Behavior on the ListView (see [this solution](http://lazycowprojects.tumblr.com/post/7063214400/wpf-c-listview-column-width-auto)).
The both approaches seem to be valid - but only for the controls that are rendered from the early beginning.
In my case, the ActualWidth is always 0 when the calculations are made, and these calculations are not repeated when the ListView is made visible.

So, I guess, the *real* question here is **how to get the columns' Width to be re-evaluated when ListView's ActualWidth gets greater than 0.**

The solution would preferably be at the XAML level, without involving the code-behind - but that will do too, if that's the only alternative ;-)

Any suggestions?

**P.S.** Following Chris's question below, here's a clarification on how the ListView is hidden/shown: it's a child of another container control, hosted in a Grid column, and the width of that column is manipulated by a trigger.

```
<ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition.Style>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="4*"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OpenItems.Count}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="ColumnDefinition.Width" Value="0"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ColumnDefinition.Style>
</ColumnDefinition>
```

I tried to apply a similar trigger to the ListView's container itself (to manipulate its Visibility between Collapsed and Visible) instead, but the problem with that is that the Column doesn't shrink from its original 4* width, so I see the (empty) control when it's supposed to be hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you hiding/showing the ListView?  The question seems to imply that you are doing so by setting the Width property to 0 (or non-zero to show it).  Instead, you should try using the [Visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) property (set to "Collapsed" to hide, or "Visible" to show).  This should cause the column's width to be re-evaluated.

UPDATE:

Based on your updated question, I'd suggest checking out this solution: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/ListView_layout_manager.aspx

I got it from here FWIW: [WPF : Extend last column of ListView's GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911243/wpf-extend-last-column-of-listviews-gridview)

Comment: Chris, I updated the original question with more details.
Hopefully this would shed more light on the situation...