# Remove empty space/column on the right handside

Tags: wpf

in Wpf listview/gridview, how can I possibly remove empty space/column on the right handside ? 
Anyone familiar with this annoying extra space ? I'd like to avoid setting fixed width, as I want my control to be fully sizeable.

Thanks for reading me ;)

```
            <GroupBox>
                <DockPanel>
                    <ListView>
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Header="RIC" />
                                <GridViewColumn Header="Last tick" />
                           </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
                </DockPanel>
            </GroupBox>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking... do you want to columns to resize automatically to fill the available space?

Comment: Have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911243/wpf-extend-last-column-of-listviews-gridview

Comment: I read something about "bindings". Is it possible to bind the size of my two columns to half of the size of the actual listview/gridview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas Levesque showed a link to the solution in comment :

The solution sits on that page [WPF : Extend last column of ListView's GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911243/wpf-extend-last-column-of-listviews-gridview)