# Truncating GridViewColumn in a ListView rather than scrolling

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a ListView which occasionally has content in one column that makes it wider than available space, causing a horizontal scrollbar to appear.

What I would like to do is have the content of the columns truncated so that all the columns are visible and the horizontal scrollbar does not appear.

I know I can disable the scrollbar but that just makes the columns that are off screen inaccessible.

Comment: You want the columns truncated so that the horizontal scroll bar does not appear, but you want to access the truncated content?  I think you don't want to truncate.  Do you want the width of the ListView/columns to auto size to fit the content?  Or do you want to try wrapping the content?

Comment: No, I do want to truncate the content, I just want to make sure all the columns are on screen, even if the user cannot see all the content in the columns.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/911243/wpf-extend-last-column-of-listviews-gridview) question.  You need to hack the ListView to allow you to use Star sizes for the columns.  If you set your most important columns to Auto and the less important ones to Star, they should shrink to fill the screen and not go off the edge.