# HOWTO Remove the extra empty space(column) on the right handside of a WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview, listviewitem, gridviewcolumn

I have an WPF ListView with three columns. I see that in my ListView appears an extra empty space(column) on the right handside and I do not know why. How can I remove this extra space using XAML?

[image]

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          Grid.Column="0"                             
          AlternationCount="{Binding pathList.Count}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding pathList}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn x:Name="LvItemId" 
                            Header="#"
                            Width="20"
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding (ItemsControl.AlternationIndex),
                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Path"
                            Width="350"
                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource NameColumnTemplate}"/>
            <GridViewColumn  Header="Edit | Delete"
                             Width="80"
                             CellTemplate="{StaticResource AddDelItemTemplate}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/911243/wpf-extend-last-column-of-listviews-gridview

Comment: @ZSH these solutions are not working for me. i have tried several of them discussed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `HorizontalAlignment` property of the `ListView` to `Left`to prevent it from stretching horizontally:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"
          Grid.Column="0"                             
          AlternationCount="{Binding pathList.Count}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding pathList}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left">
          ...
```